# How to run specific file first before anything else happens in docker run

Tags: docker

I have following docker file.

```
MAINTANER Your Name "youremail@domain.tld"

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

There is one file that I want to run even before app.py file runs. How can I achieve that? I don't want to put code inside app.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to use a docker-entrypoint.sh script. Basically that entrypoint would allow you to define a set of commands to run to initialize your program.

For example, I could create the following docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [ "$1" = 'app' ]; then
   sh /run-my-other-file.sh
   exec python app.py
fi
exec "$@"
```

And I would use it as so in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["app"]
```

There is a lot of articles and examples online about docker-entrypoints. You should give it a quick search I am sure you will find a lot of interesting examples that are used by famous production grade containers.

Comment: I was look for this. Just was not aware of naming, Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a bash file called run.sh and put inside

app.py

try changing the CMD

```
CMD [ "run.sh" ]
```

Also make sure permission in executable for run.sh

Comment: How I can achieve it, where I can't change ``` CMD [ "app.py" ], yet I want to achieve it

Comment: docker run -it <image-id> bash and execute the program and run the docker